# In Internet Explorer, how does one debug a webpage embedded via an object tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, developer-tools

I have a page which is being embedded within another page using an object tag, i.e. `<object data="page2.html"></object>`

For some reason IE seems to be rendering the content inside the object tag using the ie8 document mode, but I can't get any information on it using the dev tools. The "DOM Explorer" panel shows me the object tag, but not what's loaded inside it, and the dev tools tell me the page is displaying in edge mode, which presumably the "primary" page is, but the embedded page apparently is not.

Is there some way to get the dev tools to display the contents inside an object tag?
If not, how could I go about debugging the contents?

Comment: if you know where the other page exists (page2.html) what is preventing you from typing that path directly in your browser and then debugging that page directly?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `object` rather than `iframe` in this instance? I work on the Internet Explorer team and will gladly make mention of this to our F12 devs next week.

Comment: -crazymatt - The page works when I access it directly, but is broken when I access it through the object
-JonathanSampson - The page is being accessed via LTI in the Moodle LMS; the object tag was their design decision.